# ios Facebook login not working if logged in through settings

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

Ok, I have a weird problem. I am trying to implement facebook login for my iOS app. I have correctly configured the bundle identifier, appID, display name, url in the xcode as well as facebook app.

Now, the problem is when I am logged into my facebook account in the settings on the device and try to login through my app, it doesn't login. When I Log the error it just shows this :

```
Error : Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x17d3c4c0 
{com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x17e8a6d0, state: 
FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 275766602565473, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x17d555a0>, 
expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

This happens only if the user has set up facebook in the settings page of the device. If I remove my account from there and just have native facebook app installed, it logs me in perfectly. I have even checked the allow this app to access facebook in the settings page.

Implementation of facebook login is standard, using the documentation on the facebook developer guide : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

I can't figure out the error. I am breaking my head over this full day. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

which permissions are you asking for?

are you also asking for offline_access?

if yes, then please remove it.

Comment: I am not asking for any permission ! Just public_profile